# How to take data backup using cassandra-snapshotter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cassandra

I have to take the data backup of my cassandra nodes and upload it to amazon AWS s3. When I execute the following command,

```
cassandra-snapshotter --aws-access-key-id=**** --aws-secret-access-key=**** --s3-bucket-name=inblox-exp-buck --s3-bucket-region=ap-southeast-2 --s3-base-path=test1 backup --hosts=52.64.45.152,52.64.28.145 --user=ubuntu
```

I get the following error,

```
[52.64.45.152] Executing task 'node_start_backup'
[52.64.28.145] Executing task 'node_start_backup'

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.28.145), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Aborting.
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.28.145), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.45.152), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Aborting.
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.45.152), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'node_start_backup'

Aborting.
[52.64.45.152] Executing task 'clear_node_snapshot'
[52.64.28.145] Executing task 'clear_node_snapshot'
[52.64.28.145] sudo: /usr/bin/nodetool clearsnapshot -t "20150416144918"
[52.64.45.152] sudo: /usr/bin/nodetool clearsnapshot -t "20150416144918"

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.28.145), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Aborting.
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.28.145), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.45.152), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Aborting.
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: 52.64.45.152), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'clear_node_snapshot'

Aborting.
One or more hosts failed while executing task 'clear_node_snapshot'
```

What is happening here? How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra-snapshotter does ssh to the host, so make sure you have your 'ubuntu' user's rsa-pub key listed in .ssh/authorized-keys file. Optionally, you can turn-off ssh option in code.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the password is required to access the hosts,
same problem I found and I solved it by passing password as well

for help:

```
$cassandra-snapshotter backup -h
```

in your command should be like

```
 cassandra-snapshotter --aws-access-key-id=**** --aws-secret-access-key=**** --s3-bucket-name=inblox-exp-buck --s3-bucket-region=ap-southeast-2 --s3-base-path=test1 backup --hosts=xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx --user=ubuntu --password=*****
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to take backup.

**Setup**

- 3 Node cluster
- Separate machine that runs backup command
- All are aws ec2 machines.

I have used below command.

```
cassandra-snapshotter --s3-bucket-name=BUCKET_NAME \
--s3-bucket-region=us-east-1 \
--s3-base-path=CLUSTER_BACKUP \
--aws-access-key-id=KEY \
--aws-secret-access-key=SECRET \
 backup \
--hosts=PUBLIC_IP_1,PUBLIC_IP_2,PUBLIC_IP_3 \
--sshkey=YOUR_PEM_FILE.pem
```